# Flag a node n days after its creation

Tags: 7, rules, flags

Similar to Drupal Answers, I'm creating nodes that are questions. Once I create a question node, I want to have it flagged as 'unanswered' if a user doesn't flag it as 'answered' within 10 days. I have Flags module setup so I can click 'answer/un-answer this question' on the node itself and Views displays the unanswered questions. I'm thinking that the Rules module will be of assistance here, but I do not see a way to start a timer (for lack of better words) in Rules once a node has been created.

Thank you.

Comment: Please note that you can use the "7" tag to flag questions as being about Drupal 7 instead of writing it in your question.  Tagging makes it easier for people to search for your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to enable Rules Scheduler, which is a sub-module included as part of the Rules module.

You can watch a screencast on how to use Rules Scheduler from Node One [here](http://dev.nodeone.se/en/introducing-rules-scheduler).